# List of entire Adobe RGB colour space as hexadecimal?

Tags: colors, hex, adobe, rgb

I'm currently doing a project with colours, and was wondering whether there was a list or some way to generate a list of all of the Adobe RGB colours in hexadecimal?

Thanks!

Comment: This is just from reading the wiki article which says the values are [0,0,0] ... [1,1,1] as decimals, so I'm probably missing the point.  Do you just mean a table of 000000 through FFFFFF ?

Comment: @DaveS yeah, something like that would be ideal really

Comment: Just a 16,777,216 row list of numbers?

Comment: @DaveS as ridiculous as that sounds... Yes

Comment: Is this a PC or Mac or ...?  (What languages can we use?)

Comment: @DaveS It's for use in a project that will be written in python on pc

Comment: @DaveS Thank you! I will try this out in the morning, thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python script, if run like this it will write them to a 128 megabyte file

```
 python hexen.py > reallybiglist.txt
```

Here is the script

```
# write int as 6-digit hex
def int_6_hex(intval):
  hex = ""
  while intval != 0:
    hexValue = intval % 16 
    hex = toHexChar(hexValue) + hex
    intval = intval // 16

  while len(hex) < 6:
    hex = "0" + hex

  return hex

# Convert an integer to a single hex digit in a character 
def toHexChar(hexValue):
  if 0 <= hexValue <= 9:
    return chr(hexValue + ord('0'))
  else:  # 10 <= hexValue <= 15
    return chr(hexValue - 10 + ord('A'))

#loop to ffffff
def main():
  intmax = 256*256*256
  # intmax = 256  -- to see a preview
  loopint = 0
  while (loopint < intmax):
    print(int_6_hex(loopint))
    loopint = loopint + 1

main() # Call the main function
```